Why SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM Exception is triggered for setAlarmClock from VS2022 on Android 12 Emulator ONLY?
Regarding this documentation Android 12 should not be able to trigger "Exact Alarm" without "SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" permission :
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12?hl=fr#exact-alarm-permission
And regarding this one (https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/alarms/schedule?hl=fr#set-exact-alarm) there is 3 methods using exacts alarms :

setExact()
setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()
setAlarmClock()

But the fact is :
On my 1.12 app version, SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM isn't checked in manifest, but my real Android 12 device was able to use setAlarmClock. I'm sure of that because I added logs of this operation. Moreover, I checked through Git and the manifest file doesn't contains SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM for the 1.12 version.
Also,  when I started to work on my 1.13 Debug version, from Visual Studio, VS2022 started to throw exception when setAlarmClock is triggered on my Android 12 Emulator (api_31) only (whereas I'm also using Android 14 emulator - api 34 - and no exception is occuring).

Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'Caller com.o4d.dringcat needs to hold android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM to set exact alarms.'

It was pretty weird, but I added it to Manifest.
So I have so many questions :

How is it possible that my Android 12 device can trigger, in my 1.12 app version (without SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM) the alarmManager.setAlarmClock method (and succeed) ?
Why VS2022 started to warn me only recently ? (i'm pretty sure I was able to launch alarm without any exception before : I'm testing on Android 14 and 12 emulator only)
Why the Android documentation says SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM is needed for Android 12 AND upon, whereas my VS2022 is not throwing exception when I'm testing on my Android 14 emulator ?
And finally why my Android 14 emulator can trigger exact alarm without this permission ? (I checked my Emulator and "Developper Options" were disable, so no way to bypass this behavior). Unfortunately I can't test real Android 14 device actually.

About the numbers 2&3 I suppose it can be linked to an update on Android SDK/Tools, Visual Studio or maybe MAUI Nugets Packages ? Or maybe a melting them ?
Thank you in advance for your help : I would really appreciate some lights to understand theses behaviors.

UPDATE October 7, 2024 ; Device Logs
Emulator Android 12 :
10-07 18:03:25.273  pixel_5_-_api_31    Error   31291   mono-rt java.lang.SecurityException: Caller com.o4d.dringcat needs to hold android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM to set exact alarms.
10-07 18:03:25.273  pixel_5_-_api_31    Error   31291   mono-rt [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.SecurityException: Caller com.o4d.dringcat needs to hold android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM to set exact alarms.
 ---> Android.OS.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.alarm.AlarmManagerService$5.set(AlarmManagerService.java:2539)


And everything is fine on my Android 14 emulator :

Update October 11, 2024 : permissions difference
With the advises of user10627299 I uninstalled the app from the Android 14 and Android 12 emulators, then reinstalled it from Visual Studio. The issue is still occuring : Android 12 crash (normal behavior) whereas Android 14 is scheduling exact alarm without SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission
But, here is what I discovered in the app permissions (I didn't change anything before I took the screenshot ! The only permissions explicitly required to the user is the notification Access, usefull on Android 14)

It looks like the Android 14 Emulator device gave natively the "Schedule alarms or event reminder".

What is your .net version for 1.12 app version and  1.13 version? Please check the device log when debug your 1.12 app in the Android 12 devices. Will you get the same SecurityException. What is your Target-Android Framework version?

The 1.12 and 1.13 versions are using the same .NET 8.0 version. Both of them are targetting Android 14 (API 34). I took a look to the device log but, for the moment, I don't find any SecurityException on Android 14 ; I'll look closely theses following days and will add a comment if I find something

Ok, before testing it, please uninstall your application in the device and then make a test.

I'm not pretty sure to know what is the device linked to your device. By the way I uninstalled my 1.14 (currently developped, SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission UNchecked on manifest) from Android 14 (api_34) emulator, then run the app from VS2022 to the same emulator : the app was reinstalled and I was able to schedule an alarm through SetAlarmClock.

I think I can answer to my own 3 and 4 questions following new researchs (about the Android 14) : Even if the documentation is saying that SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM is mandatory for Android 12 (api31) and above, it's not true.
There is another way, but introduced since Android Tiramisu (api33) : USE_EXACT_ALARM
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#USE_EXACT_ALARM
This one :

Allows apps to use exact alarms just like with SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM but without needing to request this permission from the user.This is only intended for use by apps that rely on exact alarms for their core functionality.

It is what I'm using, and so it allows my app on android api_33 (and above) to NOT have SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM and works (until the Play Console warning, but it is another subject...)
So now I have, in my manifest file :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

The maxSdkVersion is important because documentation is saying "Note that only one of USE_EXACT_ALARM or SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM should be requested on a device."
About the point n°2 I think there was an update (between VS, Maui Nugets packages, Emulators etc.) which trigger the warning.
But unfortunately, about the point n°1 it's a mystery : I can't explain why my real Android 12 device was able to trigger exact alarm on my 1.12 without SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission

Thanks for your  update, you can accept your own question

I do not have the answer for my point one ; but maybe USE_EXACT_ALARM is compiled as "SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" for Android device before 13 ? I will set my answer as valid btw, the main parts of my questions found their answers.
